# VBA Public Function assigned to dynamically created Button returns Error "Object doesn't support..."

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking this up for hours and although I have found various answers to my question, none of them seem to work, so perhaps this will (thank you in advance!). I am currently running a sub routine within a main function that dynamically creates a button in a dynamically created (and specified) sheet (Forecast) within the workbook - when the button is clicked, I would like to run a series of functions that are in different modules however still within the same workbook. However, at the moment I am just trying to get one function to work. For this, I am using .OnAction with what I thought was the proper syntax for calling a public function, however when I run my code, it returns the error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Here is what that chunk of code looks like.

```
Set ApplyFilters_Button = Forecast.Buttons.Add(103, 299, 159, 21)

'Change Command button Display and Format

Set Button_AF = Forecast.Shapes(ApplyFilters_Button.Name)
With ApplyFilters_Button
   .Caption = "Apply Filters/Judgement"
   .Font.Size = 11
   .OnAction = "'Fill_SummaryTable """ & Forecast & """," & DataChart_start &    
       "," & End_Cust_List & " '"
End With
```

The function that I am trying to attach is a public function and looks like this with the following inputs:

```
Fill_SummaryTable(Forecast, DataChart_start, End_Cust_List)
```

where forecast is a worksheet, and DataChart_start and End_Cust_List are both integers.

Any thoughts/suggestions on why this isn't working? 
Thank you!

Comment: At which line exactly the error occures?

Comment: It occurs at the .OnAction line, when I comment that line out the code works just fine

Comment: The OnAction value is a String - you can't pass a worksheet object into that.  Try `Forecast.Name` instead.  I'm guessing the first parameter in `Fill_SummaryTable` is String-type, since you have that in quotes in your `OnAction` value?

Comment: The first parameter, Forecast, is the value I assigned to the sheet itself when I added it in. Should this be in single quotes? And if so - what should that entire line look line, then?

Comment: Changing it to Forecast.Name worked! Thank you! One quick question --- when I click on the generated button, an error pops up saying "Object required" in the function that is called and it highlights a specific line - do I need to modify Forecast now in the function for it to work?

Comment: Yes, you need to use `Worksheets(Forecast)` to get from the string variable `Forecast` to a worksheet named with the value of the variable.

Comment: Unfortunately actually, when I click on the button now, an error pops up and says "Cannot run the macro 'Forecast! etc...'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled." Not sure why it can't find it.

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot that kind of error remotely - go into the VB editor and make sure your project is compiling without any errors `Debug >> Compile VBA Project`